# MassTransit Kafka Consumer Not Being Called

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, .net-5, masstransit

So I am trying to setup kafka with MassTransit.

I am able to publish a topic as I can see it on conduktor:
[image]

Problem is that when I want to consume it with MassTransit it seems not to call my consumer code.
I have tested elsewhere with Kafka-Sharp to test the consuming and that seems to work.

But with MassTransit it seems a binding is broken somewhere.

There are also no errors occurring so I am pretty much clueless at this point.

As you can see it is binding to the topic according to MassTransit:
[image]

My Worker Code:

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        private static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) => Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                services.AddClient();

                services.AddMassTransit(x =>
                {
                    x.UsingInMemory((context, cfg) => cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context));

                    x.AddRider(rider =>
                    {
                        rider.AddConsumer<ClientCreatedConsumer>();

                        rider.UsingKafka((context, k) =>
                        {
                            k.Host("localhost:9092");

                            k.TopicEndpoint<Null, IClientCreatedMessage>("IClientCreatedMessage", "test", e =>
                            {
                                e.AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Earliest;
                                e.ConfigureConsumer<ClientCreatedConsumer>(context);
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
                services.AddMassTransitHostedService(true);
            });
    }
```

My Consumer Code:

```
public class ClientCreatedConsumer : IConsumer<IClientCreatedMessage>
    {
        private readonly ILogger<ClientCreatedConsumer> _logger;

        public ClientCreatedConsumer(ILogger<ClientCreatedConsumer> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<IClientCreatedMessage> context)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Message Recieved!");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

My Topic Interface:

```
    public interface IClientCreatedMessage
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
```

My Startup on an ASPNET Core API where my producer sits:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddClient();

            services.AddMassTransit(x =>
            {
                x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) => cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context));


                x.AddRider(rider =>
                {
                    rider.AddProducer<IClientCreatedMessage>(nameof(IClientCreatedMessage));

                    rider.UsingKafka((context, k) =>
                    {
                        k.Host("localhost:9092");
                    });
                });
            });
            services.AddMassTransitHostedService();

            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo {Title = "Test.Api", Version = "v1"});
            }); 
            
            services.AddMvc();
        }
```

The Code where I Call and Produce the Topic that sits in a endpoint call:

```
                var producer = context.RequestServices.GetService<ITopicProducer<IClientCreatedMessage>>();

                producer?.Produce(new
                {
                    Id = 3
                });

                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Client has been created!");
```

This is what putting a Consumer on Conduktor catches when the message is sent from my producer:
[image]

Comment: Change From  : IConsumer<IClientCreatedMessage> To : IConsumer<ClientCreatedMessage>  Your controller is parsing receive message and if the type of message return is not matching Class type you will not call the method ClientCreatedConsumer

Comment: Maybe, or the serialization format is not compatible and MassTransit is unable to determine the message type from the JSON content.

Comment: @jdweng Tried changing it to a class and it didn't work sadly.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson My producer actually uses the same class/interface that the consumer uses to consume off of. So the object would be the same. Or are you referring to any other logic for serialization as there isn't any. The Class only contains a get set property of int and it's the id of the client.

Comment: Where is the code that is producing the message to the topic? Is it using MassTransit, or something else?

Comment: Is th repsonse exactly the same as your producers?  The route and action name are used to call your method() ClientCreatedConsume.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api and https://masstransit-project.com/usage/configuration.html#console-app

Comment: I have added the producer code and a screenshot of a consumer on conduktor side to show the information passed. I hope this helps answer your questions.

Comment: Also something to note is that I am using docker on my windows machine that houses the confluentinc/kafka and confluentinc/cp-zookeeper linux containers.